Delta Points Question
Delta has a policy on not using the last leg of an international ticket. Do I lose the frequent flier points on the whole flight, or just the last leg?

What did Delta say when you asked them?

Can you point to a source or reference describing this policy? If there's a policy, it probably wouldn't be just for international tickets. You definitely will not accrue points for any legs not flown. I don't think any airline has a blanket policy of automatically not crediting points for the other legs (many people have legitimate reasons not to fly some legs, it's not always hidden-city ticketing). It's probably more of a possible consequence of doing it repeatedly (in which case they can probably void all points, including other unrelated flights) than an automatic thing.

@Traveller: asking Delta about what they would do if you intentionally violate their rules seems like a bad idea. That would clearly alert them that you are up to something.

@Hilmar Of course. It’s just that we’ve had a spate of questions recently where the OP doesn’t mention if they made any effort to research the answer, and what that research revealed, before posting their question.

Delta (as many other airlines) actively prohibits hidden-city ticketing.
How they will react for any individual case is unpredictable. It can range from doing nothing to cancelling your frequent flier account, wiping our all your miles and banning you for life. In extreme cases, people have been dragged to court (but not by Delta yet).

This is technically correct but unnecessarily alarmist: if you no-show to a single flight, you will not get your points for it, but that's it.  Sanctions only start to apply if you make a habit of this.
